# Drawing a grid using dynamic 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, grid

I am trying to draw a grid using dynamically allocated 2D array.
Here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    int i,j;
    int width;
    int height;     

    printf("");
    scanf("%d %d",&height, &width); 

    char** arr=malloc(sizeof(char*)*height);
    for ( i = 0; i<height;i++){

            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*width);

        }

    for ( i = 0; i<height; i++){
        for ( j = 0; j<width; j++){

                arr[i][j] =  '+' ;
                printf("%c\n", arr[i][j]);

            }
        }   


    for (int i=0;i<height;i++){
        free(arr[i]);
    }   
    free(arr);


    return 0;


}
```

And if I type `2 2` for height and width,it returns

```
+

+

+

+
```

But I am expecting to get

```
+
+

+
+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing a newline after each datum, not after each *row* of data.

Change this:

```
    for ( j = 0; j<width; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] =  '+' ;
        printf("%c\n", arr[i][j]); // WRONG: newline after each cell
    }
```

to this:

```
    for ( j = 0; j<width; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] =  '+' ;
        printf("%c ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);  // RIGHT: newline after each row.
```

and for what its worth, the array is utterly useless if all you want to do is draw a grid. Just draw the grid.